# React Functional Component Not Receiving Async Data, Seems to Stop Running Mid-Function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous

My firebase component retrieves the data I want (a boolean that tells me if the user is an admin or user). But I cannot get it to pass this boolean to the Login component that needs it. In fact, the code seems to stop running after the initial call, as I do not get any subsequent logs to console.

I haven't been able to Google anything that seems to address this specific issue, which usually means I need to back way up and broaden my search. I imagine there's something intrinsic to the function component dynamic I'm just not getting.

I've boiled this code down to the minimum needed to get the result I want. If we can just get this checkAdminStatus call to log "true" (when it is actually true), I can take it from there. Thanks!

Login.js:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext'
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { checkAdminStatus } from '../firebase';

export default function Login() {
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const { login } = useAuth();
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const history = useHistory();

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            setError('');
            setLoading(true);

            setStatus(checkAdminStatus(emailRef.current.value));
            console.log(status);
            await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);

        } catch {
            setError('Failed to log in');
        };
        setLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>

            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <h2>Log In</h2>
                    {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group id="email">
                            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required>
                            </Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group id="password">
                            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required>
                            </Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button disabled={loading} type="submit">Submit</Button>
                    </Form>
                    <div className="w-100 text-center mt-3">
                        <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</Link>
                    </div>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            <div className="text-center mt-2"><Link to="./SignUp">Or Sign Up Here</Link></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

firebase.js (this all works)

```
const db = firebase.firestore(app);
const user = app.auth().currentUser;
const colRef = db.collection("users");

export async function checkAdminStatus(emailRef) {
    if (emailRef !== null) {
        console.log(emailRef);

        await colRef.doc(emailRef).get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data().isAdmin);
                return doc.data().isAdmin;
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the database. Feel plenty dumb about this one. I couldn't return the boolean because it was returning from within the nested function, not from the called function itself. Lesson learned!

```
export async function checkAdminStatus(emailRef) {
    let status = false;

    if (emailRef !== null) {
        await colRef.doc(emailRef).get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data().isAdmin);
                status = doc.data().isAdmin;
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
    }
    
    return status;
}
```